# Direction of Ik Handle Tool and joints

Tags: 3d, maya, autodesk

So, in Autodesk Maya, I have joints attached to my character's body. Then I put a IK Handle to make movements, but in this case, in the legs (see image below) the movement happens wrong because when selected a move tool for up (x), the knee goes to the side and not to front. How can I correct this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `preferredAngle` value on the joints controls the bending. It's usually set based on the initial orientation of the joints, so if the un-rigged bones have a slight bend before you attach the IK they will use that to tell the IK which way to bend when the chain shortens. You can also set that value manually before applying the IK handle.

Comment: tks @theodox, but does have anyway to change the angle of ik handle movement after attach? Or another way to correct this, like a I delete this joint replace one adjusted?

Comment: The pole vector placement will be set at creation time based on the preferred angle you had when the IK was created.  The flexion should respect the preferred angle settings but you can also lock the rotation on the non-planar axes.  That does sometimes make the handle respond oddly